# why frame setter effect of button title come back?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

when I want to change the postion of title of button. I found the Strange phenomenon。

btn.titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(btn.titleLabel.center.x+10,btn.titleLabel.center.y);

this method have proble!

[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, a.origin.x +5,0,0)];

this method is good!

why  the effect of the first method come back after click up!

Comment: Please put some more work into your question. This is subpar. What button are you talking about? UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the implementation of UIButton positions it's titleLabel based on the edge insets. So you can set the position manually, but it will be reset every time because the insets say so.

In other words, just use the edgeInsets property and let UIButton position the titleLabel.